# Array to List Automapper Issue

Tags: c#, collections, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map array to list through AutoMapper but I am not able to map. 
My BEntity.Products List is always coming null.

List to Array mapping is working perfectly fine.

Below are the classes that I am tryin to map.

```
public Class ProductsModel
{
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public Class ProductsEntity
{
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}



public Class AModel
{
    public ProductsModel[] Products {get;set;}
}

public Class BEntity
{
    public IList<ProductsEntity> Products {get;set;}
}
```

//assuming I have values in object of AModel named model.

```
mapper.Map<BEntity>(model);
```

Automapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<ProductsModel, ProductsEntity>();
CreateMap<ProductsEntity, ProductsModel>();
CreateMap<AModel, BEntity>();
CreateMap<BEntity, AModel>();
```

Please let me know how can I map Array of a class to list of class.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the setter for the list property?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I am assigning values to the list and mapping them to an array. setter is there.

Comment: Then we need a repro. It works for me.